# Regular expression count underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How it's possible to count and find `underscore` via `Regex` then if it's higher than 2 underscore and less than 4 *(continuously)* *do something* and if more than 4 underscore *do something else*.

```js
$('div').text(function(i, text) {
  var regex2 = /_{2,4}/g;
  var regex4 = /_{4,999}/g;
  //var regexLength = text.match(regex).length;

  if (regex2.test(text)) {
    return text.replace(regex2, '،');
  } else if (regex4.test(text)) {
    return text.replace(regex4, '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Blah_Blah _ BlahBlah __ test ____ Blah _________________________________________
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is, find more than two, less than four underscore continuously, replace with `comma` else if more than four underscore replace with `nothing`.

**Now:**

```
<div>
  Blah_Blah _ BlahBlah __ test ____ Blah _________________________________________
</div>
```

**Goal:**

```
<div>
  Blah_Blah _ BlahBlah , test , Blah
</div>
```

**Problem:**

The second `regex` *(more than four underscore)* not working as expected.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38npuxjf/1/)</kbd>

Comment: `_{2,4}` matches 2, 3 or 4 underscores. `_{4,999}` matches 4 and up to 999 `_`s. Your patterns overlap.

Comment: Check for `4,999` first then check for `2,4` in else clause.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/ckrk0o95/2/, are after this? `return text.replace(/(_{5,999})|_{2,4}/g, function($0,$1) {return $1 ? '' : '،';})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So close. but after `test` should do another `comma`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, it help me out.

Comment: Ok, so it was https://jsfiddle.net/ckrk0o95/2/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly is. much appreciated.

Comment: My code will be helpful if you plan to match differenet symbols. If you just need to match an underscore, anubhava's solution is the most concise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For now the issue is `underscore` but i'm pretty sure in future i need to add some more. because this used as a cleaner for user input. I think both are efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do this in a single regex without multiple regex `test` and `replace` calls:

```js
var str = 'Blah_Blah _ BlahBlah __ test ____ Blah _________________________________________'
var r = str.replace(/_{2,}/g, function(m) { return (m.length>4 ? '' : ',') })
console.log(r)

//=> Blah_Blah _ BlahBlah , test , Blah
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string = "Blah_Blah _ BlahBlah __ test ____ Blah _________________________________________";
const count_underscore_occurrence = (string.match(/_/g) || []).length;
```